# Is it possible to COUNT and ADD Values from both a row and a cloumn?

Tags: excel

If I have both a row and column containing the numbers 1 and 2 with some blank spaces in there as well, would it be possible to count how many 2s there are in the row and how many 1s there are in the column so that I get one total value?

For ex. there are three 2s in the row, and two 1s in the column so I would like a formula that would give me the total, which would be 5 without making two separate totals and then adding them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure:  For example:

[image]

Note the formula in the picture above.

Comment: Does this only work in row 1 and column A? I tried using the formula in row 15 and column E for example and doesn't work.

Comment: For some reference, there are three 2s @ B15, E15 & F15, and two 1s @ E9 & E11